# My gmap app is not working when I upload it to Google Play

Tags: android, google-maps

My android application using gmap, I have check the api and everything is working fine when I test it in my cell phone. But the map is not loading when I uploaded it to Google Play and download it to my phone. Here is my gmap Api

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

So what's going on here? Why my app is different when I upload it to Google Play?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUs1M.png)

Comment: Maybe you have restrictions in your api_key. Debug sha-1 and release sha-1 are different. You need to supply the fingerprints of your release keys in the Google Dev. Console.

Comment: But how to change it? I don't see any option about Debug and Release sha-1. It's just add the package name and it's done. Thank you so much!

Comment: You can add debug (package name + sha-1) and release (package name + sha-1) in Google Dev. Console.

Comment: I don't know what are debug (package name + sha-1) and release (package name + sha-1). I have added the photo of my Google api console could you show me where to find the Realease sha-1?

Comment: There is a button (Add package name and fingerprint), you can add another pair of package name and fingerprint.

Comment: Ok, I have found the solution here! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25867876/android-sha1-release-keystore-not-working-with-google-maps

Comment: I have two google_maps_api.xml files, one in the app/src/debug/res/values folder and the other in the app/src/release/res/values folder, but only the debug one contains your API key.