# Google maps doesn't show in play market

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm using Google Map V2 in my app. When I publish my app to tablet on my computer, It does work. But after publish in play market, Map doesn't show.

I had create a lot of new API_KEY on Developer Console but It doesn't work.

I run this code on cmd:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\mtt\.android\debug.keystore -alias debug
```

I have debug.keystore:

```
86:3B:F3:2C:71:2F:B1:94:AC:1B:65:B6:F9:35:23:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

I added SHA-1 fingerprint and package name in Android Key of My developer console

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyAMlGbSo8dByFvRIY07xxxxxxxxxx" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
```

I read a lot of topic about this problem but no result. Please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25867876/android-sha1-release-keystore-not-working-with-google-maps

Comment: you need to create new SHA1 value from keystore

Comment: If you use android studio, you can create a template project that it support map. "Google Map Activity" to get new SHA1 value.

Comment: @AkarshM i have already created a lot of SHA1

Comment: @sonnv1368 yes I use Android Studio but why I must create template ?

Comment: @TimCastelijns no duplicate

Comment: @mobileprogramming, i mean to get right sha1.

Comment: @mobileprogramming why not?

Comment: @sonnv1368 when I do that your saying, I see xx:xx:xx:xx:xx;com.test.program

But I can't this SHA1 in my developer console

Comment: @TimCastelijns What may be duplicate ? keystore or api_key ?

Comment: @mobileprogramming: let replace this sha1 on the your developer console. Please keep your package name.

Comment: @mobileprogramming *What may be duplicate ?* um, your question may be a duplicate

Comment: @sonnv1368 I can't add packagename end of SHA-1

Comment: Change that package name by your app package (same package name of app that you have published on the google play )

Answer (score 0):

Use your production keystore to generate SHA1 that will be used for generating map API key.

[More information about it](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#horzTab)

Comment: I have created new SHA1 using my keystore :

`keytool -list -v -keystore D:\Android\Android_Workspace\Test\test.jks -alias mobileprogram`